# dynamic column name selection in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am stuck in Mysql today with the dynamic column name need in mysql select statement. Let me explain:

```
sql> select name1 from namescollection. 
sql> select name2 from namescollection. 
sql> select name3 from namescollection.
```

So namescollection table has three columns having name1, name2, name3
I would like to query this table in my stored procedure being 1,2,3 as dynamic and would be passed as a variable, but on the simple sql too when i query:

```
SELECT concat('name','1') FROM `namescollection`
```

`name1 ----- name1 rather fetching name1 field's value.`

Can any suggest on this, the right function i need to use rather concat though I know its right to output name1 when I am calling concat but I want to use it as column name.

Comment: I don't understand. What's wrong with just using `SELECT name1`, `SELECT name2`, and `SELECT name3`?

Comment: Why don't you use PHP string cat?

Comment: I need to use it in stored procedure @codetiger and phMyCoder

I wanna execute it as call procedurename (1) 

//2,3,4 like so it may change to 5 or 8 in next days, months or years

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you can do is use a prepared statement within your stored procedure which will allow you to execute a string query:

As a simple example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE selname (IN col VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', col, ' FROM tbl');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

---

Test it out with this [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b7f/2/0)

Comment: Thank you so much Zane. Found this as solution and tested and worked fine. I thought SQL must have some function too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

**Dynamic column name in store procedure Update statement** :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selname`()
BEGIN
    declare cl int ;
    declare clvalue int ;

    set cl=1;
    SET clvalue=1;
    while cl < 4 DO
        SET clvalue=clvalue*cl;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('update test set col',cl, '=',clvalue,' where id=1');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        set cl=cl+1;
   end while;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```