# Unable to pass parameter in Mysql procedure with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create what I thought to be a fairly simple procedure calling in parameters for the column name.

This is the procedure I have created:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(in col varchar(225))
BEGIN
-- Column of Averages
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS temp; 

CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS 
  SELECT col, 
         Round(Avg(bcount), 0) AS `Average # of Loans` 
  FROM   (SELECT col, 
                 Count(borrower) AS bcount 
          FROM   whatif_dataset 
          WHERE  loan_lienposition = 'first' 
          GROUP  BY col, 
                    Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')), 
                    Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')))AS dt 
  GROUP  BY col; 

END
```

However when I call the procedure I only get one record i.e:

```
Col                Average # of Loans
'Passed Parameter'   757
```

It seems to me like the parameter is not being passed through correctly. Is there some limitation in MYSQL that wont allow me to do this?

When I run the same query with the specific column name currentprocessor this is the desired result :

```
    currentprocessor    Average # of Loans
    proc1               20
    proc2               12
    proc3               8
    proc4               22
    proc5               24
```

Comment: What are you expecting?  You probably need a prepared statement, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699027/dynamic-column-name-selection-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you, I used a prepared statement to get the desired results

Comment: Nice, looks good.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this corrected by using a prepared statement

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(in col varchar(225))
BEGIN
-- Column of Averages
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS temp; 


SET @sql= CONCAT('SELECT ', col,',', 
         'Round(Avg(bcount), 0) AS `Average # of Loans` 
  FROM   (SELECT ', col,', 
                 Count(borrower) AS bcount 
          FROM  whatif_dataset 
          WHERE  loan_lienposition = ''first'' 
          GROUP  BY ', col,', 
                    Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, "%m/%d/%Y")), 
                    Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, "%m/%d/%Y")))AS dt 
  GROUP  BY ', col); 

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: this is a example given below  of dynamic column name procedure may be this is also helpful for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699027/dynamic-column-name-selection-in-mysql/29141630#29141630