# Programmatic column names and where conditions in update statement

Tags: mysql

I am using subqueries to update columns in another table. However, the where condition values depend on the column, and there are many columns. I have a table associating the column name and the where condition value.

Here is the hard coded update statement (truncated)

```sql
UPDATE table_a SET
    column_x=(
        SELECT some_value
        FROM table_b
        WHERE 
            condition_b=value_x
    ), 
    column_y=(
        SELECT some_value
        FROM table_b
        WHERE 
            condition_b=value_y
    ), 
    ...
;
```

Ideally, I only have to write one subquery and the column being set + the condition's value are generated programmatically.

```sql
# Just an example 
# column_value_map contains (column_name condition_value)

UPDATE table_a SET
    column_name=(
        SELECT some_value
        FROM table_b
        WHERE 
            condition_b=condition_value
    )
    FROM column_value_map
;
```

If this cannot be done, is there a simple way of iterating through each column_?/value_? pair?

---

Edit: A more concrete example.

```
UPDATE training_image SET
    left_hand_label=(
        SELECT heatmap_label
        FROM annotated_frame
        WHERE 
            annotation="left-hand"
    ), 
    right_hand_label=(
        SELECT heatmap_label
        FROM annotated_frame
        WHERE 
            annotation="right-hand"
    ),
    ...
;
```

Comment: You can do it using [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11699027). Nevertheless, this is almost always a warning sign that you have to. A typical example for "x" is a year or month, e.g. "column_2019, column_2020, column_2021". The correct solution would be "column, year", and group by year in a single update. You may want to be more concrete with your example for us to be able to tell you if this is might be one of those cases.

Comment: Hi, I included a concrete example. I will look into dynamic SQL. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is also one of those cases. The "relational database way" would be to store the different annotations as rows, e.g. columns "feature_name, label", and then rows with ("left_hand", "abc"), ("right_hand", "xyz"). Nevertheless, to just get things working the way you want it to (or for speed optimization or output format reasons), dynamic sql should probably get the job done. Feel free to ask if you need help with it (this is not supposed to be a "If you don't do it the right way, noone will help you"-comment), and if you get it working yourself, feel free to answer your own question.